# Spring and OpenLayers conflicts on label rendering?

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to use Jquery to handle other elements on the webpage. I tried to put labels on a vector layer with the following style:

```
  var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style({
            'fillColor': 'red',
            'fillOpacity': .8,
            'strokeColor': '#aaee77',
            'strokeWidth': 3,
            'pointRadius': 8,
            'label': "${name}",
            'labelAlign': "cc",
            });
```

But the labels do not show.

I am just wondering if there is a conflict on this one  "${name}".
I tested it again with a simple page without Jquery. The labels do show.
Please let me how to fix this. Thanks.

**Update:**
I just figured out the conflict may come from Spring or JSTL. I use Firebug tool to check the javaScript source code of the style. It appears as this:

```
    var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style({
            fillColor: 'red',
            fillOpacity: .8,
            strokeColor: '#aaee77',
            strokeWidth: 3,
            pointRadius: 8,
            label: "",
            labelAlign: "cc",
            });
```

I returned an variable from the server side:

```
    model.addAttribute("name", "test");
```

then all features show the label "test". It approved that ${name} is recognized as a spring variable.

Comment: have you checked your browser's console for errors? Perhaps that will help you/us understand what's going on. On IE you can access the console with F12, on chrome with CTRL+SHIFT+i

Comment: Usually there is no conflicts, when using jQuery and OL's "${name}" type styling together. For testing, turn 'label': "${name}" into 'label': 'foo' and check, whether labels show up or not.

Comment: I checked with the firebug. 
`map.layers[0].styleMap.styles.default.defaultStyle.label` returns null
and `map.layers[0].features[0].attributes.name` returns the value.

Comment: if I use ` 'label': 'foo' `,the labels show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the javascript code into a separate *.js file now. This avoids the conflict between the spring $ variable and openlayers $ variable.

Answer (score 0):

No. jQuery and OpenLayers use separate name spaces.

I guess you not providing a value to the label attribute of your Feature object.
Did you know that?

Also you do not need put 'quotes' in your object label names.
You can write this instead:

```
label: "${name}"
```

A feature object has the following constructor:

```
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector( geometry, attributes )
```

To you configuration work the attributes variable above must contain a label property like on example below:

```
{ name: 'this will show' }
```

Comment: if I use the fixed label, like  ` 'label': 'foo`, it will show.
and  i can get the value from map.layers[0].features[0].attributes.name

Comment: You ca use the "value" of attribute name as the label with the following as already explained on answer: 'label': '${name}'. This will make OpenLayers search for the property name into feature been drawed.